# How to hide physical body's stroke in Sprite Kit

Tags: objective-c, sprite-kit

I have a game in which i have some sprites using physical body and it has a stroke around a physical body. How to hide it?! [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4cvU.png]

Comment: Try setting `scene.view.showsPhysics = NO;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somewhere in your code, you might have set

```
self.view.showsPhysics = YES; //Within the scene
```

or

```
skview.showsPhysics = YES; //from the viewcontroller
```

The `showsPhysics` method tells the SKView to actually draw the physicsBodies on top of the nodes they are associated with. A description of the method is given in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKView/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKView/showsFPS).

Either remove the above lines or set the `showsPhysics` property to `NO` in order to solve this problem.